# How to use a DVR hard disk drive on a Windows PC

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

I am trying to use a SATA hard disk drive of 2000GB capacity from a DVR on a Windows 8.1 PC.

I connected the drive to the SATA port and even though it shows up in the PC's boot menu, I can't find it anywhere in Windows Explorer.

Does anyone have any idea about what can be done?

Comment: It'll depend on the file system in use. You can check Disk Management for the drive and assign a drive letter, and if that doesn't work then find out what file system the video recorder uses and install a driver to support that file system.

Comment: Please clarify what exact you mean by “video hard disk drive”. Did you take it from a digital video recorder? Or a video security system? If so, what make and model are they?

Comment: @DanielB yes I took it from a DVR.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the dusk or get footage off it? Reusing the disk is easy - you just need to repartition (maybe) and format it. If you need to access the data on it we really need to know the make and model of the DVR. Most likely you will need to get the OS to understand the file firmat - but we dont know which one is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out. It was a long process but i finally got it working. Below are the steps I took to get it working just for future references

1. I connected the hard disk drive to the SATA port of my PC.
2. I Inserted a windows installation disk into my PC's CDROM drive.
3. When the Disk was loaded and everything was shown, I clicked on format to clear all the data on the disk and that automatically set the filesystem of the disk to N T filesystem which windows uses.
4. I rebooted my PC and finally I now have a 2000GB hard disk drive working on it. Still wondering what I am gonna be needing that much space for.

Thanks for the responses.